# When the page is updated the data is deleted - vue and laravel sanctum

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

I am using vue and laravel in a project, I have sanctum configured in laravel, when I update the page the data is deleted I get an Unauthorized message. I tried to set vuex-persistedstate in the project, but it doesn't work, I was also trying to create an interceptor to read the token that is stored in the localStorage but nothing.

The problem is when I reload the page again, the requests it makes to the api seem to be lost and you have to log in again, Unauthenticated shows me

I am using vuex.

**configuration .env:**

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
```

**Api url path configuration:**

```
export default {
  state: {
    apiURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api',
    serverPath: 'http://localhost:8000',
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
}
```

**General vuex settings:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

// Modules
import ecommerceStoreModule from '@/views/apps/e-commerce/eCommerceStoreModule'
import app from './app'
import api from './api'
import appConfig from './app-config'
import verticalMenu from './vertical-menu'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    app,
    api,
    appConfig,
    verticalMenu,
    'app-ecommerce': ecommerceStoreModule,
  },
  strict: process.env.DEV,
})
```

**This is a part of the login file configuration:**

```
if (success) {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
        .then(() => {
          axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login', {
            email: this.userEmail,
            password: this.password,
          }).then(resp => {
            const login = resp.data
            const tokenOriginal = login.accessToken
            const token = tokenOriginal.replace(/["']/g, '')

            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', JSON.stringify(token))
            localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', JSON.stringify(token))

            axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
            axios.defaults.headers.common.Accept = 'application/json'

            axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/user')

              .then(response => {
                const user = response.data.data
                const { role } = user

                localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(user))

                this.$ability.update(user.ability)
```

**axios configuration file:**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '@/store/index'

export function http() {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: store.state.api.apiURL,
  })
}

export function httpFile() {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: store.state.api.apiURL,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  })
}
```

**configuration file path:**

```
export default {
  state: {
    apiURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api',
    serverPath: 'http://localhost:8000',
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
}
```

**Services file:**

```
import { http } from '../http_service'

// Inventory
export function getInventories() {
    return http().get('/store_inventory')
}
```

Comment: Firstly, I would recommend not hardcoding the domain/port for your axios calls. Secondly, have you added `localhost:8000` to the `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` domains?

Comment: yes I already added it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the headers to the axios configuration:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '@/store/index'

export function http() {
 return axios.create({
 baseURL: store.state.api.apiURL,
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Authorization': `Bearer 
   ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken').replace(/['"]+/g, '')}`
  }
 })
}
```

I get the accessToken from the localstorage and every time the page is reloaded the information is refreshed and does not appear anymore **unauthorized**

Answer (score 0):

sanctum login is depend on cookies not local storage
you must add `with_credential: true` to axios options
and it is good to use this library to make authintication https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sanctum

Comment: Adding withCredentials I get this: Request from other origin blocked: same origin policy prevents reading remote resource at 'http: // localhost: 8000 / api / cost_centers' (reason: credential is not supported if CORS header' Access-Control-Allow-Credentials ' it is '*').